# Search for git issue that contains a specific string in title using requests library python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, get, github-api

I am using requests library to search for git issues. I want to search a git issue that contains a specific string ("has issues") in the title of the issue. I have tried various approaches, but my search results do not get filtered by the string.

```
def search_issue():
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/issues" % (REPO_OWNER, REPO_NAME)
    print(url)
    session = create_session()
    session.params = {'q':'has issues+in:title', 'state': 'open', 'type': 'issue', 'sort': 'created', 'direction': 'desc'}
    r = session.get(url)
    pprint(r.json())
```

```
def create_session():
    # Create an authenticated session
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = (USERNAME, TOKEN)
    return session
```

How do I pass the params to session such that the results get filtered by the string "has issues" in title? Other params, like state: open or closed and direction: asc or desc are working fine. But I'm not able to filter based on title.